# Set UINavigationBar with 2 different fonts

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uinavigationbar

I have to set my UINavigationBar with 2 different fonts. I need to have such picture:

[image]

It's very easy to create a custom title, but with only 1 font, I've found suck solution:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],
              NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size:21]
   }
 ]
```

But is it possible to co create a title using 2 different fonts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code -

```
 UIFont *font1 = [UIFont fontWithName:kMyriadProSemiBold size:15];

NSDictionary *arialDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: font1 forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

NSMutableAttributedString *aAttrString1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My" attributes: arialDict];

UIFont *font2 = [UIFont fontWithName:kMyriadProRegular size:15];

NSDictionary *arialDict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: font2 forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

NSMutableAttributedString *aAttrString2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Profile" attributes: arialDict2];


[aAttrString1 appendAttributedString:aAttrString2];
myProfileLabel.attributedText = aAttrString1;
```

May be you have to change little bit in this code.